# How to rewrite the ast to use cache value for function in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to write a Fibonacci program in Python and it will rewrite the AST to use a cache to avoid intermediate calculation if possible.

My current implementation will find all ast.Call and transform them to ast.Constant node. However, I cannot get the correct result from the code below. I suspect it's due to I am not using func args properly.

Really appreciate your help! Thanks.
Code in Python3.9.7

```
    import ast
    import inspect
    import types


    class Rewrite(ast.NodeTransformer):
        def visit_Call(self, node):
            func_name = node.func.attr
            if (func_name, self._func_args) in self._cache:
                print(
                    f"Hitting cache: {self._func_args} to get {self._cache[(func_name, self._func_args)]}"
                )
                return ast.Constant(self._cache[(func_name, self._func_args)])
            return node


    def dag(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _self = args[0]
            func_args = args[1:]
            source = inspect.getsource(f)
            lines = source.splitlines()[1:]
            lines[0] = lines[0].lstrip()
            source = "\n".join(lines)
            old_code_obj = f.__code__
            old_ast = ast.parse(source)
            rewriter = Rewrite()
            rewriter._cache = _self._cache
            rewriter._func_args = func_args
            new_ast = rewriter.visit(old_ast)
            ast.fix_missing_locations(new_ast)
            new_code_obj = compile(new_ast, old_code_obj.co_filename, "exec")
            print(ast.dump(new_ast))
            print("dumped")
            new_f = types.FunctionType(new_code_obj.co_consts[0], f.__globals__)
            value = new_f(*args, **kwargs)
            print(f"args: {args}, kwargs:{kwargs}")
            print("value", value)
            if (f.__name__, func_args) not in _self._cache:
                _self._cache[(f.__name__, func_args)] = value
            print(f"cache_after", _self._cache)
            return value

        return wrapper


    class Rick:
        def __init__(self):
            self._cache = {}

        @dag
        def fibonacci(self, n):
            return 1 if n < 2 else self.fibonacci(n - 1) + self.fibonacci(n - 2)


    Rick().fibonacci(4)
```

Comment: IMHO, you could simply use [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functools.html#functools.cache) instead of modifying the AST

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying to modify the AST because functools.cache seem a bit ad-hoc to me. Imagine we have many methods on a class and they have dependency (basically on a dependency graph), I think AST hacking is the only viable solution here.

Comment: What if you implemented your own memoizing decorator, or a metaclass, or a class decorator which passed all the methods of that class through a memoizing decorator?